How to implement 3rd person animation with acceleration from walk to run?
I am new to Unity and I am using dr Penny de Byl's lectures on Unity.
I am trying to use a Mixamo character. I downloaded a character with skin as an fbx file, and also added some character movement animations without skin.
I am trying to add character movement animation using user input for character movement as well as accelerating from walking to running using the animator. As of now, the character is not moving but I think my camera is.
I am using the new Input System package. However, the main camera shows that there is no movement when I check the transform panel in the inspector.
Can someone help me figure this out?

Can you share the code you're using to read input amd pilot the animator controller?
